# Why does one machine assume unicode and another non-unicode for same database columns in SSIS OLE DB Source task?

Tags: oracle, unicode, ssis, oledb, sql-server-2016

A coworker made an SSIS package that pulls data from Oracle and transfers it to a SQL Server database that is nearly identical, so it's a lot of data flow tasks simply with an OLE DB Source (Oracle) to an OLE DB Destination (SS). When I open it on my computer, I get the error "Column [column name] cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types" on all the source tasks. If I add a data conversion task to convert the unicode columns to non-unicode, all works fine but I really want this to work like how he has it because it's running on the production server like this. My best guess is it has to do with the installing of the Oracle client or drivers or the NLS_LANG variable but I can't seem to solve it. My environment variable NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1

[image: SSIS data flow task]

I was worried something went wrong with my Oracle client installation because of my registry values. Now I have 3 clients installed since I went through the install process again. These are the third client's reg values and I added NLS_LANG myself and rebooted. I'm more of a SQL Server developer, so I'm possibly saying something wrong here.

[image: Registry values]

Comment: The `NLS_LANG` environment variable takes precedence over registry settings. Which OLE DB provider do you use? The Microsoft (`MSDAORA`) or the Oracle (`OraOLEDB.Oracle`)?

Comment: I'm using the Oracle Provider for OLEDB. But as I've just posted below, I solved it by setting NLS_LANG (and I agree it takes precedence over registry because they didn't match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the NLS_LANG environment variable value to AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252 to match what my coworker had and what my registry has because I somehow didn't notice they were different! However, neither NLS_LANG were set to start with so the real solution was to add this in. I rebooted and when I reopened the package, got zero errors.